# Display date and time received from Server as is, without compensating for timezone

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, .net-core

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I have tried different solutions, none seem to work for me.

My server/API is hosted in South Africa, while the clients connecting are situated either in South Africa, or Dubai.

When displaying the dates to a user in Dubai, it should display the date as Saved in South Africa, and not convert to their timezone.

Here is my .Net Core API setup:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(setup =>
            {
                setup.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                setup.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                setup.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
                setup.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                //options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "mm/dd/yy, dddd";
            });
```

On the API, I am using `DateTimeZoneHandling = Local`.

On the Angular application, I have written a `HttpInterceptor` to intercept incoming dates, to try and modify them to display correctly, but fail in doing so.  Here is an example of a method in my Interceptor that tries to preserve the date as received from the API.

```
shiftDates(body): void {
        if (body === null || body === undefined) {
            return body;
        }

        if (typeof body !== 'object') {
            return body;
        }

        for (const key of Object.keys(body)) {
            const value = body[key];
            if (this.iso8601.test(value)) {
                console.log('Original', value); //2021-03-23T13:24:15.047+02:00
                let strippedDateString = String(value).split('+02');
                let strippedDate = new Date(strippedDateString[0]);
                console.log('Stripped Date: ', strippedDate); //Tue Mar 23 2021 13:24:15 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)
                console.log('New date: ', new Date(strippedDate.getFullYear(), strippedDate.getMonth(), strippedDate.getDate(), strippedDate.getHours(), strippedDate.getMinutes(), strippedDate.getSeconds())); //Tue Mar 23 2021 13:24:15 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)
                body[key] = new Date(strippedDate.getFullYear(), strippedDate.getMonth(), strippedDate.getDate(), strippedDate.getHours(), strippedDate.getMinutes(), strippedDate.getSeconds());
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                this.shiftDates(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Even though I have tried different methods for displaying the date exactly as received from server, Javascript still adds the timezone, and a different time is displayed on the UI.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I prevent this?

Example:

Let's assume a user, sitting in Dubai, creates an order for collection on '2021/03/24 12:39:00', my API would receive it as such a date and time, and save it correctly in the DB.
Now, when the same user views the order, the collection time would be displayed as '2021/03/24 14:39:00', which is incorrect, as I would like it to display as '2021/03/24 12:39:00'.

Is this approach possible with the `Http Interceptor`

Comment: Could you please say what is `stringify` function used here?

Comment: hmm.. Seems instead of typing String(value).split('+02'), it used stringify(value).  Changed it, but the results are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, by implementing the following two `HttpInterceptors` on the Angular project:

Interceptor to intercept outgoing dates to the Server/API in different timezone:

```
@Injectable()
export class DateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'GET' ) {
            this.shiftDates(req.body);
        }
        return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(evt => {
            if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                this.shiftDates(evt.body);
            }
        }))
      }
    
      shiftDates(body): void {
        if (body === null || body === undefined) {
            return body;
        }
    
        if (typeof body !== 'object') {
            return body;
        }
    
        for (const key of Object.keys(body)) {
            const value = body[key];
            if (value instanceof Date) {
                body[key] = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a \'+0000\'');
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                this.shiftDates(value);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Interceptor that intercepts incoming dates and modifies them:

```
@Injectable()
export class IncomingDateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    iso8601 = /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?(([+-]\d\d:\d\d)|Z)?$/;
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(evt => {
            if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                this.shiftDates(evt.body);
            }
        }))
    }

    shiftDates(body): void {
        if (body === null || body === undefined) {
            return body;
        }

        if (typeof body !== 'object') {
            return body;
        }

        for (const key of Object.keys(body)) {
            const value = body[key];
            if (this.iso8601.test(value)) {
                body[key] = Number(`${String(value).substr(0, 4)}`) + "-" + Number(`${String(value).substr(5, 2)}`) + "-" + Number(`${String(value).substr(8, 2)}`) + " " + Number(`${String(value).substr(11, 2)}`) + ":" + Number(`${String(value).substr(14, 2)}`) + ":" + Number(`${String(value).substr(17, 2)}`);
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                this.shiftDates(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```